# Auto Refresh ListView in Fragment when Data is inserted in database

Tags: android

I have a fragment class which is called when the tab is clicked. After inserting the data into the database listview in fragment doesnot auto refresh. The listview only refresh if reopening the application or only if current tab is opened only after switching other tabs. Help me to auto refresh the listview of current fragment.

SocialFragment.java

```
        package layout;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import com.example.kiran.herau.NewDatabaseAdapter;
        import com.example.kiran.herau.R;


public class SocialFragment extends Fragment {

    protected BaseAdapter mAdapter;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    NewDatabaseAdapter vivzHelper;
    TextView text;

    Context context;

    @Nullable

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fifth, null);

ListView lb = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        context = getActivity().getBaseContext();
        vivzHelper = new NewDatabaseAdapter(getActivity());
        Cursor cursor = vivzHelper.fetchAllData();

        // The desired columns to be bound
        String[] columns = new String[]{

                NewDatabaseAdapter.NewDatabaseHelper.UID,
                NewDatabaseAdapter.NewDatabaseHelper.TEACHER_NAME,
                NewDatabaseAdapter.NewDatabaseHelper.SUBJECT_NAME,
                NewDatabaseAdapter.NewDatabaseHelper.START_TIME,
                NewDatabaseAdapter.NewDatabaseHelper.END_TIME,

        };

        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[]{
                R.id.uid,
                R.id.date,
                R.id.time,
                R.id.subject,
                R.id.end_time,
        };

        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
        //as well as the layout information

        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                context, R.layout.routinerow,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);

        lb.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(R.id.empty));
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        lb.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have the code to tell you when the database gets updated, you can just call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

like -

```
public void methodThatIsCalledWhenDatabaseUpdates(Datatype data){
     adapter.setData(data);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```